# There is another way to record the Audio or Video instaid of MediaRecorder class in android?

Tags: android

I want to know the different ways to record the audio in android. Is there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are other ways. For example you could use the [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class.